# Why is Loop Cut and Slide not in the CTRL+E/F menu?

Tags: modeling, shortcut

How can I get to Loop Cut and Slide via a popup menu? I can only find it in the T side bar.

Neither <kbd>W</kbd> nor any of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>/<kbd>F</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd> menus seem to show me the *Loop Cut and Slide* tool.

I seem to only be able to find it in the <kbd>T</kbd> bar on the left. Am I missing another popup menu shortcut available for modelling operations? I'm a newcomer to Blender.

Comment: Make sure that you are in "edit" mode.

Comment: That's not the case for me. CTRL+E opens the *Edges* menu, CTRL+F opens the *Faces* menu and CTRL+V opens the *Verts* menu for me. W opens up the *Specials* menu.
**[Here's a screencap of what it looks like for me.](https://gfycat.com/TerriblePlasticGnat)**

My question is why the **Loop Cut and Slide** tool isn't listed in any of those popup menus. The **Bevel** tool is also listed in there although it has its own shortcut (CTRL+B).

Comment: I am in edit mode.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, Loop Cut and Slide is available currently only as a shortcut (Ctrl-R) and in the Toolshelf, in the Mesh Tools panel, as stated here: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop_subdivide.html

Comment: Is there any good and pressing reason why that is? Or could it be added to the popup menus (presumably best in the edge and poly tools I guess?) if I were to contact the right person about it? And if so, who would be the right person to contact? ;)

Comment: @Chris Offner, I believe it's because with its own shortcut Ctrl-R it's much faster to work with than going through a menu-submenu tree in Ctrl-W. You can then increase the numbers of the loop cuts with the mouse wheel.

Comment: @metaphor_set Yeah but as I said before, being in the menu-submenu tree doesn't preclude a tool from having its own shortcut as well. Bevel for example also has its shortcut (CTRL+B) **and** can be found in the dropdown menus. It's much easier for beginners like myself to find the tools they need if they can be found in menus as well - especially since most modelling tools seem to be listed there.

Comment: @ChrisOffner Campbell already said it should be in Edge menu, so maybe it will be there next release.

Answer (score 1):

It's on the Dynamic Spacebar Menu under Edit Mesh Tools.  You have to enable the Dynamic Spacebar addon in User Preferences to this however.

Comment: Thank you, but in that case I can just as well call it via the T menu side bar. :)